# How can I make a webpage that will display the contents of a file that is constantly being updated?

Tags: javascript, python, html, simulation

I have been messing around with python to write code for small projects that I come up with to do for fun, and the most recent one I've been working on is a simulation of a house. For instance, I create the data structures of a house that has three rooms that are connected to each other, then I have a Person object that can move through the rooms based on how they are connected. That's all that it does now, and the only way to see the simulation's progress so far is through a file that I called "output.txt" that the program prints its state to for each iteration of the simulation. The file lists the rooms in the house, how they are connected, and who is in each room currently. This is a sample output:

```
Room: Kitchen
Connections: Living Room, Dining Room
Actors in Room: 
Bob, Sue

Room: Living Room
Connections: Kitchen
Actors in Room:
Joe

Room: Dining Room
Connections: Kitchen
Actors in Room:
```

I'm writing all this on a server I built not too long ago so eventually I can just let it run and see what happens, and right now I have it set up so that I can go to a link and see the contents of the file. I wanted to do this so I could just refresh the page to see the changes instead of having to open the file every time I wanted to see what changed. The problem is that sometimes I think the program is in between writes to output.txt so nothing shows up when I refresh the page.

I'm wondering if there is some way that I can make the webpage just show the output of the program live, without even having to refresh. Here is how I'm writing to the output.txt file in a python program:

```
while(True):
    home.tick()
    output = open("/var/www/html/output.txt", "w")
    output.write(str(home))
    output.close()
```

The home.tick() statement basically goes through all the people in the house and tells them to go through their tick methods, which at this point just makes them wander through the house. Then to display output.txt I have an html file with

```
  <h1>House Simulation</h1>

  <pre id="simulationContents"></pre>

  <script>
      function populatePre(path) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload = function() {
              document.getElementById('simulationContents').textContent = this.responseText;
          };
          xhr.open('GET', path);
          xhr.send();
      }
      populatePre('output.txt');
  </script>
```

which, as I said, works sometimes, but sometimes I think the python is still working on the page when I refresh it so it shows up with nothing.

I'm new to html and javascript, so any help would be appreciated. This is also just a fun project for me, so if there's a better way to make the output go to the webpage other than html and javascript, I'm definitely open to it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you could run them on the same box, you can use an <input type=file> to load the data from javascript itself. you can also check the file.size before reading it, so you can avoid loading empty files.